# Which matrix implementation does Incanter 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT use?

Tags: matrix, clojure, incanter

I keep seeing references in the documentation to both Parallel Colt and Clatrix, confusing me. Which implementation is used in 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In version `1.2.2`](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/blob/1.2.2/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/core.clj#L35) they have been using [Parallel Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) - [`cern.colt`](https://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html) extension.

Then they replaced it with [`clatrix`](https://github.com/tel/clatrix), so there is no trace of Parallel Colt in latest `Incanter 1.5.x`.

[Judging from Incanter Changelog](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/blob/master/Changes.md#changes-for-150), they changed internal matrix implementation in `1.5.0` major release, so in `1.2.3` it was still Parallel Colt.